# Divergence in CUDA - exit from a thread in kernel

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm wondering how can I exit from a thread, whose thread index is to big. I see two possibilities:

```
int i = threadIdx.x;
if(i >= count)
    return;
// do logic
```

or

```
int i = threadIdx.x;
if(i < count) {
    // do logic
}
```

I know, that both are correct, but which one affect more the performance?

Comment: Both will give you same performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although both are the same in terms of performance, you should take into account that the first one is not recommended.

Return a thread within a kernel could cause an unexpected behaviour in the rest of your code.

By unexpected behaviour I mean whatever problem related to the minimum unit of threads that are grouped in a warp. In example if you have an `if / else` block in your kernel, this situation is known as thread divergence and in a normal case it results in threads remaining idle and others executing some instructions.

CUDA by Example Book, Chapter 5, Thread Cooperation:

> But in the case of __syncthreads(), the result is somewhat tragic. The CUDA Architecture guarantees that no thread will advance to an instruction beyond the __syncthreads() until every thread in the block has executed the __syncthreads()

So, it is mainly related to the threads synchronization within a kernel. You can find a very good question / answer about this topic here: [Can I use __syncthreads() after having dropped threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666382/can-i-use-syncthreads-after-having-dropped-threads)

As I final note, I've also used that *bad practice* and no problem appeared but there is no guarantee that problems may arise in the future. It is something that I would not recommend

Comment: What do you mean unexpected behavior, what is the problem? I have seen it in tutorials and I have also used it and no problem has appeared to me so far.

Comment: Please provide a reference for your claim.

Comment: @GeorgeAprilis The problem is mainly related to _good practices_ and future synchronization within a block.

Comment: As @RoBik suggested I've provided some references.